# DataTables & Droppable hit-zone off-center

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm trying to combine DataTables and JQuery UI Droppable.

When I drag over the dataTable I want an overlay to overlap the table's area. This works just fine actually. I have a `#table` that both dataTables and JQuery UI reference for their respective code.

However, the drag events (`over`, `drop`) only fire on half of the table. (The left side.)

[Here is my live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/HSA8L/1/) Be sure to drag one of the list items over the table.

I'm using Chrome 27.

I have a dual monitor set-up, and if I drag onto my other monitor with this example (assuming it's full-screen) the drag events will actually fire out outside of the window on the left side.

Here is a visual example:

[image]

I'm wondering what could be causing this? When I inspect the table with my console it shows it being where it should be, there's nothing halfway overlapping the table.

Is this a side-effect of DataTables and Droppable not working together right? I can't quite figure it out. Maybe it's just a CSS issue?

I've tried messing with JQuery UI Positioning and investigating with the console but I haven't had any success. My suspicion is that it has to do with droppable and it not getting the position of the table right (even though position does get it right, as you can visually see).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is being caused by the [droppable's tolerance option](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance); its default is `intersect`.

As stated in the API Documentation

> `intersect`: Draggable overlaps the droppable at least 50% in both
>   directions.

Seeing as how your `<li>`s are still in their default style they will fill the available width of their parent `<ul>`, if you try to drag them over the right side of the table more than 50% of the `<li>` will be hanging outside of the droppable.

By adding some borders to your `<li>`s and `#myListOfData` you can get a better picture of what's going on.

**[Figure 1](http://jsfiddle.net/HSA8L/3/)**

**So now that we know what the problem is, on to the solutions.**

You can as [Pepper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413807/1947286) said just change the tolerance option of the droppable to pointer:

[**Working Example 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/HSA8L/4/)

```
    $('#table').droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer', //Important Bit
        over: function (event, ui) {
            $('#tableOverlay').width($(this).width());
            $('#tableOverlay').height($(this).height());

            $('#tableOverlay').show();
            $("#tableOverlay").position({
                of: this,
                at: "top left",
                my: "top left"
            });
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
            $('#tableOverlay').hide();
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $('#tableOverlay').hide();
        }
    });
```

Or you could use `tolerance option: 'touch'` like so:

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/HSA8L/6/)**

```
    $('#table').droppable({
        tolerance: 'touch', //Important Bit
        over: function (event, ui) {
            $('#tableOverlay').width($(this).width());
            $('#tableOverlay').height($(this).height());

            $('#tableOverlay').show();
            $("#tableOverlay").position({
                of: this,
                at: "top left",
                my: "top left"
            });
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
            $('#tableOverlay').hide();
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $('#tableOverlay').hide();
        }
    });
```

Or you could specify a width for your `<li>`s like so:

**[Working Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/HSA8L/7/)**

```
#myListOfData li {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Or if you would rather not change the tolerance option or specify a width you could use
 `display: table;` like so:

**[Working Example 4](http://jsfiddle.net/HSA8L/8/)**

```
#myListOfData li {
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the incredible answer! Hopefully Pepper awards you that bounty, you sure deserve it for this detailed answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `tolerance: "pointer"` made it work as expected for me.